# Oracle SQL Developer Giving error while making monnection

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Whenever I try to make a new connection it give an error that

```
Status : Failure - Test Failed: Connection property: format error: property is 'v$sessoj.osuder' and value is 'user name'
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Does it really say `v$sessoj.osuder`, or `v$session.osuser`? What is your operating system and your user name in that (e.g. your Windows login)? I can only imagine it's more than 30 characters, but I might have expected it to be truncated if it was longer.

Comment: Got my answer. Oracle Sql Developer do not username having parenthesis. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly that problem, my computer's name has parenthesis, I solved it by adding a line in the 'ide.conf' file, you can check the steps here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72623763/19340528

Hope it helps!