# How do I reformat v$session.osuser?

Tags: weblogic, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to set up an Oracle WebLogic Datasource for my job. But every time I try to connect to the database, I get this error:

Connection test failed.
Message icon - Error Connection property: format error: Property is 'v$session.osuser' and value is 'Yann (Intern)'

I tried changing my username to "YannIntern" to remove the special characters, but the error is still the same and it also happens when I try to use Oracle SQL Developer. How can I stop the format error?

Comment: I don't know the answer. Though, if possible, try to use uppercase (e.g. YANNINTERN). In Oracle, username is stored in uppercase by default so ... maybe that's what prevents you from establishing connection.

Answer (score 1):

Java reads this from the user.name property which defaults from the os username. However, this can be overriden by  setting -Duser.name=Yann

Here's an example in sqlcl

```
SQL> select  sys_context('userenv', 'os_user') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER')                                                                                                                                                                       
------------------------------------
klrice                                                                                                                                                                                                 

 <<< a short command to set java properties >>> 
 <<< which is the same as a -D property     >>>

SQL> set property user.name kris 
Setting user.name to kris (klrice)


SQL> @connect-klrice
Connected.
SQL> select  sys_context('userenv', 'os_user') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER')
----------------------------------
kris

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me, I have parenthesis in my computer's name. I spent a lot of time researching but finally, I have the solution (I created an account just to answer this haha). To solve this you have to:

-Go to the folder location where you installed SQL Developer.
-Then go to: \ide\bin\ide.conf
-At the end add the following line:

```
# Custom VM Option
AddVMOption  -Duser.name=<YourUsername>
```

-Save the file, and restart SQL Developer, you will be able to connect and avoid that error message.